# Is it the best way to directly include HTML template using AngularJS like IFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

In my current project I want to get facility to include different template inside my body section to preview it. It can be easily done by using IFrame but I don't need to use it due to some technical challenges. So I am including and previewing template directly using AngularJs.

Is it the good way to do it? and also wanted to know is there any better alternative ?

**Requirement**
I have an dashboard where I have an option to preview other Single page application (SAP) templates. Both SPA have some customization to be done that will be depends on each other. For example we directly update template title from preview section that should be reflected on template from dashboard.

So the basic problem I am getting while using IFrame to achieve these I am not able to communicate these two SPA with each other for run time edits.

Comment: Can you explain in brief about your requirement and why you don't want to use IFrame.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not good way due to: id's, css rules, js functions, invalid html tags(such as `<head>` `<meta>` etc...

Comment: Yes I know it is not valid way to do but I don't find any alternative to achieve these.